# How can I show/hide options in a select when another option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an Unnoficial character creation tester for the popular game Mount & Blade. The script should in theory, depending on the options chosen, determine the characters stats as it would do in game.

At the moment when I choose male/female in the select box none of the specified fields disappear. What have I done wrong?

When the stats are changed I want to automatically display them in  a tabular form, would that require me to give an id to each td or could I somehow reference which cell so like the third cell from the left two cells down would be table1(3,2) or is that too difficult/impossible?

Here is the Javascript:

```
// Base Stats - 
var sGender; // Male or Female
var iAgi = 6;
var iStr = 5;
var iInt = 5;
var iCha = 5;

$("#selGender").change(function() {
    var mnf = $(this).val();
    sGender = parseInt(mnf);
    if (sGender = 1){
        // Show/hide options
        $('#fnomad').hide();
        $('#fnoble').hide();
        $('#fsquire').hide();
        $('#mnomad').show();
        $('#mnoble').show();
        $('#msquire').show();
        iAgi++;
        iInt++;
        this.disabled=true;
    } else {
        $('#mnomad').hide();
        $('#mnoble').hide();
        $('#msquire').hide();
        $('#fnomad').show();
        $('#fnoble').show();
        $('#fsquire').show();
        iStr++;
        iCha++;
        this.disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<legend>Choose your background:</legend>
<label>Gender</label>
<select id="selGender"> 
    <option value="1" >Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
<label>Your father was ...</label>
<select id="selFather">
    <option id="fnoble" value="fnoble">a Noble</option>
    <option id="mnoble" value="mnoble">a Noble</option>
    <option value="merchant">a Merchant</option>
    <option value="vetwarrior">a Veteran Warrior</option>
    <option value="thief">a Thief</option>
    <option id="fnomad" value="fnomad">a Nomad</option>
    <option id="mnomad" value="mnomad">a Nomad</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: Also, I've made sure I've linked to the jQuery file in the header.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT2: this is the section where mSquire and fSquire are:

```
<label>When you grew to a young adult, you became a ...</label>
<select id="selAdult">
    <option id="msquire" value="msquire">a Squire</option>
    <option id="fsquire" value="fsquire">a Lady in waiting</option>
    <option value="troubadour">Troubadour</option>
    <option value="student">Student</option>
    <option value="peddle">Peddler</option>
    <option value="poacher">Poacher</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Both are possible. But giving an ID to each cell is easy and without important disadvantages.

Comment: Does the msquire or fsquire option exist in your drop down?

Comment: it does further down in the file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/KvNVN/

Instead of showing/hiding each element, you can add classes to them:

```
<select id="selFather">
    <option id="fnoble" value="fnoble" class="f">a Noble (f)</option>
    <option id="mnoble" value="mnoble" class="m">a Noble (m)</option>
    <option value="merchant">a Merchant</option>
    <option value="vetwarrior">a Veteran Warrior</option>
    <option value="thief">a Thief</option>
    <option id="fnomad" value="fnomad" class="f">a Nomad (f)</option>
    <option id="mnomad" value="mnomad" class="m">a Nomad (m)</option>
</select>
```

And then

```
$('.f').hide();
$('.m').show();
```

You could also create a CSS stylesheet with: `.f{display:none} .m{display:block;}`

Your code has a problem: if you have ...

```
<select id="selGender">
    <option value="1" >Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

... the default selected value is "Male", so if you select it it doesn't trigger onchange event. You can use

```
<select id="selGender">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select gender:</option>
    <option value="1" >Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

Moreover, you have

```
if (sGender = 1)
```

You should use

```
if (sGender == 1)
```

because you are comparing, not setting values.

About your other question (navigate through a table), you can create a JavaScript function which does that. But I don't understand very well what you want with "the third cell from the left two cells down".

**Edit:**

If I understand well you have a table like

```
<table id="table">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Skill 1</td>
     <td>Skill 2</td>
     <td>Skill 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Value 1</td>
     <td>Value 2</td>
     <td>Value 3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Table]

And you want

```
table(1,1)=Skill 1 cell
table(1,2)=Value 1 cell

table(2,1)=Skill 2 cell
table(2,2)=Value 2 cell

...
```

Then,

```
function table(col,row){
   return document.getElementById('table').tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[row-1].getElementsByTagName('td')[col-1];
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/UGHHd/

Comment: The reason I'd want the 3,2 cell etc. is to assign the value of it, so using the 4 stats (and all the skills etc.) I'd have a table in which would be 4 cells for the stat labels and 4 cells for the values i.e. cell 1,2 would be Str: and cell 2,2 would be the cell I'd need to change the value of when someone selects 'Male' in the gender box(because male increments the strength).

Comment: for some reason all my disabled input boxes remain disabled, any idea why ?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/rQTbb/7/. You didn't close event functions well. And if you want to enable a `select`, you can do `.disabled=false` in plain javascript or `.prop('disabled',false)` in jQuery, but don't mix them. Moreover, `iWpn1h` isn't defined.

Comment: I made a typo when I declared the variable, it should have been `iWpn1h` but it ended up being `iWp1h`, when choosing an option I can't seem to get past the third selection `(#selAdult),` as it stays deactivated, despite having the same statement made about it prior to it's execution. - `$("#selAdult").prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: @MavericktheBroken1 See http://jsfiddle.net/rQTbb/20/. I have changed the variables. And you forgot `#` in some jQuery selectors. And a `<select>` had `id="selsLeave"` instead of `selLeave`. And I have removed those `var` at the beginning (if you use `,` instead of `;` you can avoid using `var` again).

Comment: @Oriol, let me ask you (as a newbie) I don't know what `parseInt(mnf)` means? thanks a lot.